What is the convex hull of $n$ points uniformly chosen on the surface of a sphere?
Say you randomly and uniformly select $n$ points on the surface of a sphere. I wonder what does its convex hull looks like.
I'm not really interested in distances or angles. In fact, every aspect of the polyhedron I concern is contained in its planar embedding. So, what does this planar embedding looks like?
Edit: It was raised in the comments the matter of the uniqueness of this planar embedding. It is, in fact, unique. This is a consequence of Whitney's embedding theorem for planar graphs. You may find an MSE post commenting on it here. I've mistakenly quoted in the comments the Wikipedia article on Whitney's embedding theorem for manifolds, I hope this clarifies my mistake.
One thing is easy to notice: the embedding will be triangulated. This is because there is zero probability more then three points are chosen on the same plane, so every face of the convex hull is a triangle. This inspired me to consider the following process:

Start with three points on the plane forming a triangle;
Uniformly choose a face of this embedding (including the outside one) and add a vertex inside of it;
Connect the new vertex with the vertices surrounding the face it's placed in.

Is this equivalent to the process of selecting $n$ points on the sphere? If so, does this help with studying its properties? At least computationally I expect the answer to be affirmative, as we are now considering a discrete probabilistic process, but I'm just as unsure on how to approach it.

I was asked expand on the combinatorial properties I'm interested in. My motivation for considering this process lays on the fact that there are only finitely many regular lattices on the sphere, namely the ones produced by regular polyhedra such as the platonic solids. However, by uniformly choosing points on the sphere, I expect the distribution to become highly symmetrical as the amount of points increases, thus approximating something that looks like a regular lattice (except for being discrete, of course). I would like to address this suspicion by analyzing properties such as the mean and standard deviation of the degrees.

I think this is potentially interesting. Please [edit] to clarify what combinatorial properties of the embedding you are interested in.

Note that you have written of “the” planar embedding as though it were unique. Are you certain that every property that interests you is invariant across embeddigs?

@PaulTanenbaum this is a very concerning comment! However, yes, I'm sure. This is because every $3-$connected planar graphs (which is the case for triangulated planar graphs) have a unique planar embedding.

This might be useful: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1967-21-098/S0025-5718-1967-0223277-3/S0025-5718-1967-0223277-3.pdf (I found it searching for triangulation of sphere and you may find other useful links that way.)

I'm slightly confused. You are not talking about the 2-dimensional Euclidean plane?

@GyroGearloose what do you mean?

"@GyroGearloose what do you mean?": In your question and comments you talk of "planar embedding" and "planar graphs" I was wondering if this "planar" refers to the 2-dimensional Euclidean plane, and if not, what "planar" refers to in your context.

@GyroGearloose yes, it refers to the 2-dimensional Euclidean plane. Why would you think otherwise?

... because your link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem says there are 2m dimensions required for an m-dimensional manifold. I heard differential geometry only briefly, and, a long time ago, so I may remember it not correctly.

@GyroGearloose I've added a clarification on the statement, I apologize for my mistake

You start from a polyhedron. I'm not firm with geometry and what I have learned is mostly self-acquired after university, so I might miss something obvious. I don't see how you get from a polyhedron to a (3-connected) planar graph.

Instinct tells me your question is, somehow ,in a way I don't understand yet, a dual of a question I had in mind lately and that is the reason why I'm interested in your question.

Your question is about adding points on a sphere, but your reasoning is about adding points on a planar graph. I don't see why the second should produce everything that the first can. In other words, can adding a point to your polyhedron always be followed by adding a point to your planar graph, keeping it planar?

I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection fixes your premises. No Whitney needed.
